# Why do we need copy data management(CDM)?

Tags: backup, nas

I know the CDM is very famous and vendors will said they can reduce consumption on your storage and disaster recovery or something else.

But why do we need CDM rather than NAS?

There're many NAS vendors support disaster recovery, remote replica, and incremental backup...etc to save storage and easy to recovery.

What's the main difference between them or between CDM and public cloud?

Can someone give me an example that CDM can do but NAS(or other storage server) can't do?

It's very abstract concept.

Answer (score 2):

CDM is "buzzword bingo" - I'd not heard of it until now (which is saying something) , but it is simply a sales/market term for software overlaying some fancy features allowing point-in-time recovery and a nice interface on a NAS or similar storage - which most NAS's with a web interface will do anyway.

I guess you could say a NAS or something similar (ZFS filesystem?) provides the hardware and low level interface.

A CDM provides a nice interface for this.

Comment: So the difference between NAS and CDM is the interface!? Nas offer the interface to do backup or snapshot, but CDM offer the higher interface to let normal people easy to use?

Comment: Not neccessarily.  CDM is a buzzword to sell expensive storage solutions. - little more.  CDM is not hardware, it is software to control access to hardware, and means whatever the seller wants it to mean.

Comment: really? so I should regard it as managing your copied data in a centrallized center?

Comment: You should regard it however the people selling you the buzzwords portray it.  (Assuming they are actually credible).     The closest thing to a simple definition I can come up with is a mechanism for handling block level (ie partition level) point-in-time recovery with a web interface - this is not exactly the same thing as managing your copied data - as - despite the name - it does not actually copy data - in overly simple terms - it keeps the original data and tracks changes, meaning it typically takes less space then multiple full copies.

Comment: Also - please don't think "CDM is very famous" - its not.  I manage storage systems for a SaaS provider, and am fairly up with the play but had never heard of it.

Comment: An example of what CDM can do - say you have a fileserver with 1TB of files on it and change 100 gigs per month, and you are worried about them all being erased or encrypted.  You set up the CDM system to take snapshots of your data periodically (say 7 x daily, 5x weekly, 12 x monthly) so that even if something happens you can roll back to an earlier version from a day, week or month ago. If you use a typical NAS, you would need 24TB of storage, and a lot of copying to do this.  With PITR (which a CDM implements), you only need 3.4TB of storage (ie 100gigs x 24 copies + 1tb).

Comment: A CDM will not neccessarily provide you with security from a hardware failure - you would still need RAID, Backups etc to protect against that - and that is not part of CDM.

Comment: Note: You can do exactly this with ZFS snapshots or any equivalent system which provides a "Copy-on-write" filesystem - although you still need a gui interface to call it a CDM.

Comment: In your example, I have one question. If I use a typical NAS, I still can use mechanism like snapshot on volume. I can set schedule to take snapshot.  So I may not need 24TB of storage.
Am I correct or miss something?

Comment: You are probably correct -  If it uses something like zfs or  btrfs under the cover, yes. If it uses something like lvm this won't work very well. (If you need to specify the snapshot size it's probably lvm).

Comment: Why " If it uses something like lvm this won't work very well" ?

Comment: 2 reasons - LVM requires you to pre-allocate the size of the snapshot, and snapshots cab have a heavy performance impact on LVM, and the more snapshots the heavier the performance impact.

Comment: got it, so more snapshot is heavior impact in the snapshot origin logical volume

Comment: Yes, in LVM. Not noticeably so on ZFS.